# Color overlay on img tag with shape

Tags: html, css

I have a image with border radius, and want to add a color overlay over the image.

```css
  img {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 60% 65%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 35%;
    border-top-left-radius: 40px 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
<img width="751" height="640" src="http://via.placeholder.com/751x640" class="" alt="">
</div>
```

The image has a oval shape with border-radius

If I add a color with pseudo element on the div/container it doesn't overlay in a oval shape but the full container.

How to place a color overlay (just for the image) on a img tag with border radius?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the end result, and possibly explain what you mean by _overlay_? You might also want to look into [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go with a pseudo, the container has to shrink on the image and image be displayed as a block or vertical-align reset to avoid the gap. From there, apply to the pseudo the same radius. a gradient overlay can even be used ;)

example:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVjdbg

```css
img,
.image-wrapper:before {
  display: block;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60% 65%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 35%;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px 200px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}

.image-wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(200, 45, 125, 0.3), rgba(15, 235, 15, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper"><img width="751" height="640" src="http://via.placeholder.com/751x640" class="" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `border-radius` on the parent element with `overflow: hidden`, then add your overlay effect:

```
.image-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 60% 65%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 35%;
    border-top-left-radius: 40px 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.5);
}
```